# Sonatype Nexus endpoint for artifact's version number

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

is there an endpoint in Nexus to get the artifact’s latest version ​**number** (pom’s version)?

If the artifact’s latest version in Nexus is 0.0.8-SNAPSHOT, the endpoint would return 0.0.8-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Nexus `resolve` REST API to obtain an XML document containing details about the POM, including the version:

```
http://nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?g=groupId&a=artifactId&v=LATEST&r=snapshots&p=pom
```

You'd then need to parse the text in the `baseVersion` element, e.g.

```
<artifact-resolution>
  <data>
    ...
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-20160000.100000-1</version>
    <baseVersion>1.0-SNAPSHOT</baseVersion>
    <extension>pom</extension>
    <snapshot>true</snapshot>
    ...
  </data>
</artifact-resolution>
```

Reference:

https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/path__artifact_maven_resolve.html